# Azure API Management service publisher portal no longer showing Analytics tab

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I noticed about 4 days ago, that the my azure apims no longer showed the Analytics tab on the left hand side navigation. This forces me to navigate by changing the URL manually to
https://sureco-apims.portal.azure-api.net/Admin/Analytics

Is there a bug with this portal? Why did the nav change?

Comment: Hi Joey, I cannot accept an answer twice. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **[31st May 2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/classic-api-management-analytics-will-be-retired-on-may-31-2019/)**, we will retire classic Azure API Management Analytics. **Analytics reports in the publisher portal will be completely removed.**

If you have been using classic Analytics, you should start using the new `Analytics`—which is integrated in our management experience in the Azure portal. Simply select `Analytics` from the menu. There is **no need to switch** between the Azure portal and the classic publisher portal anymore.

[image]

Comment: Got it. I had no idea that the disappearing menu item meant it was no longer goign to be supported. Now I know! Thank you so much for the screenshot.

Comment: Is there any way to show on publisher portal or some other portal?